# nginx redirect directory including php files

Tags: nginx

Previously my site URLs were like this:

- https://www.example.com/forums/threads/test.123/ (type 1)
- https://www.example.com/forums/showthread.php?t=123 (type 2)

Now the URLs are like this:

- https://www.example.com/threads/test.123/ (type 1)
- https://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=123 (type 2)

I'm using the following:

```
location /forums/ {
    rewrite ^/forums/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

And it properly redirects the URLs of type 1, however URLs like type 2 are returning 404. How can I make nginx to also redirect the php files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because `location` directives that are defined by regular expressions take precedence and have the final word, hence, you probably have your `location ~ \.php$` handler process the request.

As per http://nginx.org/r/location, what you should do is simply ***add the `^~` modifier*** to your existing code, to not check regular expressions, like so:

```
location ^~ /forums/ {
    rewrite ^/forums/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Another consideration is that although `$uri` (the variable that's behind the `location` and `rewrite` directives) [does not contain `$is_args$args`](//stackoverflow.com/a/47735919/1122270) (and, hence, `$1` in the example above doesn't, either), they'll still be added automatically in the `rewrite` context, as per http://nginx.org/r/rewrite, so, nothing else needs to be done to the code above.

---

As a bonus, a maintenance-related optimisation is still possible — namely, you don't actually have to specify `https` (or `$scheme`) and the host explicitly, but can let nginx figure it out based on the context.

Also, as explained at http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#internals, you can save an extra instruction by making `/` be part of the capture.

As such, with the above two optimisations, the best approach to your situation may then be:

```
location ^~ /forums/ {
    rewrite ^/forums(/.*)$ $1 permanent;
}
```

Here's the above code at work, which confirms that `$scheme://$host` (and `:$server_port`, only if needed), are automatically added, subject to the settings described at http://nginx.org/r/absolute_redirect:

```
% curl -i "localhost:4441/forums/showthread.php?t=123" |& fgrep Location
Location: http://localhost:4441/showthread.php?t=123
%
```

Comment: @imthebest, btw, i did some testing, and the code from the second snippet is actually redundant -- `rewrite` automatically adds `$args` back.

Comment: so it should simply be `https://www.example.com/$1$is_args`?

Comment: @imthebest, no, basically, just the first snippet should do the job.